# Override values.yaml in helm chart using nexus

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Helm Chart Structure

```
web-service
  |_ _ _ templates
  |_ _ _ Chart.yaml
  |_ _ _ values.yaml
```

I have helm chart setup in which my helm charts for my application are packaged `.tgz`
and pushed to nexus repo consider `https://localhost:50714/#browse/browse:helm`

Which is added to helm `repositories.yaml` using

```
helm repo add nexus https://localhost:50714/
```

Once Repo is added I can see the chart

```
helm search
NAME                                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
nexus/web-service                   1.0.0-k8s                       Custom microservice Helm chart
```

To Install I Fire the below command

```
helm install nexus/ioc-web-service --version 1.0.0-k8s
```

and application get deployed. So the application is deployed using default values.yaml
I need to make this configurable so that my default values.yaml is overridden by another file lets say 
values-override.yaml

```
web-service
  |_ _ _ templates
  |_ _ _ Chart.yaml
  |_ _ _ values.yaml
  |_ _ _ values-override.yaml
```

I used helm provision of passing extra file using `-f` command but it gives `values-override.yaml` file not found

```
helm install nexus/web-service -f values-override.yaml --version 1.0.0-k8s
```

Need Some input on how to get the pass the override values in file format. As the override values can be dynamic. On one environment it can be 1 variable in another there are be 10 variable which needs to be overridden

Comment: the override file should be in your current directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the docs for [Customizing the Chart Before Installing](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing) and you can use two ways of passing config data during installation:

> - `--values`  (or  `-f`): Specify a YAML file with overrides. This can be specified multiple times and the rightmost file will take precedence
> - `--set`: Specify overrides on the command line.

You have to remember you need to run `helm install` from the directory where your `YAML` file is sitting.

If you are still seeing the `Error: open values-override.yaml: no such file or directory`, this means that `Helm` is probably installed as a docker container. This happens if you use `Kubespray` to install `Helm` in this case can should check which folder is being mounted to the docker by:
`$ cat /usr/local/bin/helm`
You might see something like this:

```
cat /usr/local/bin/helm

#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/docker run --rm \
  --net=host \
  --name=helm \
  -v /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl:ro \
  -v /root/.helm:/root/.helm:rw \
  -v /usr/share/ca-certificates:/usr/share/ca-certificates:ro \
  lachlanevenson/k8s-helm:2.7.0 \
  "$@"
```

Which will mean you need to copy `values-override.yaml` to `/root/.helm` directory.
You can also check the directory by `$ helm init`:

```
$ helm init
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /root/.helm.
Warning: Tiller is already installed in the cluster.
(Use --client-only to suppress this message, or --upgrade to upgrade Tiller to the current version.)
Happy Helming!
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not add the `values-overwrite.yaml` in the chart. Its a file locally where you run the command. Usually created by a templating taskrunner engine like Ansible or similar on the fly.